# Question about Ito integration in SDE in Stochastic optimal control

Tags: stochastic-calculus, stochastic-integrals, stochastic-analysis, optimal-control

### Here is my question statement. I cannot understand the last equality.

Let $U=[-1,1]$.
\begin{equation}
 \mathcal{U}[0, T] = \left\{ u:[0,T] \rightarrow U \mid u \text{ is } \{\mathcal{F}_t\}_{t\geq0}\text{-adapted} \right\}
\end{equation}
For $t\in [0,1]$
\begin{equation}
 \begin{cases}
  dX_t = u(t)dB_t \\
  X_0 = 0  
 \end{cases}
\end{equation}
Then
\begin{equation}
 X_t = \int_0^t u(s)dB_s.
\end{equation}
\begin{align}
 J(u(\cdot)) &= E \left\{ \int_0^1 X_t^2 - \frac{1}{2}u(t)^2 dt + X_1^2\right\}\\
    &= E \left\{ \int_0^1 \left( \frac{3}{2}-t \right) u(t)^2 dt\right\}.
\end{align}

I attached the reference where my question arise. On page 117 in this book. It just mention "simple calculation".

Yong, Jiongmin, and Xun Yu Zhou. Stochastic controls: Hamiltonian systems and HJB equations. Vol. 43. Springer Science & Business Media, 1999.

### In summary

How is it possible? I want to know the procedure.
\begin{align}
E \left\{ \int_0^1 X_t^2 - \frac{1}{2}u(t)^2 dt\right\}
    &= E \left\{ \int_0^1 \left( \frac{3}{2}-t \right) u(t)^2 dt\right\}.
\end{align}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, simple it is: $$E \left[ \int_0^1 X_t^2 dt\right] =   \int_0^1 E\left[X_t^2\right] dt  = \int_0^1 \int_0^t  E\left[u(s)^2\right]ds\, dt \\= \int_0^1 \int_s^1  E\left[u(s)^2\right]dt\, ds = \int_0^1  E\left[(1-s)u(s)^2\right] ds = \int_0^1  E\left[(1-t)u(t)^2\right] dt.$$

Hence your equality follows, taking into account that $E\left[X_1^2\right] = \int_0^1 E\left[u(t)^2\right] dt$.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. However, I still cannot get the point..? How can you show that
$
\begin{equation}
E \left\{ \int_0^1 X_t^2 - \frac{1}{2}u(t)^2 dt\right\}
    = E \left\{ \int_0^1 \left( \frac{3}{2}-t \right) u(t)^2 
\end{equation}$

Comment: @user1820964, is it clear now? If not, what do you not understand, exactly?

Comment: In $\int_0^t  E\left[(1-s)u(s)^2\right] ds = \int_0^t  E\left[(1-t)u(t)^2\right] dt$ , I think we need the integration interval should be $[0,1]$ instead of $[0,t]$. That is the part I could not understand.

Comment: I think that I fixed a typo. Check it and if I did wrong, let me know.

Comment: @user1820964, seems correct now indeed.

Comment: Thanks :) It was really simple!